# How do I find the running microcontroller’s model?

Tags: python, microcontroller

In Python we can test if the running OS is Windows or Linux:

```
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    "Our code"
else:
    "New code"
```

Is there any way to check for the particular uC chip? What needs to be done if I want my code to get executed only if uC is TI's TMS320F28015 and don't execute it if it's TI's TMS320F2802.

Comment: Have you considered [`platform.processor`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html#platform.processor)? I don't know how much detail that will give you, though; I get `'Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel'`

Comment: I wouldn't even know how to detect those chips at the OS level; that'd be very OS specific in any case.

Comment: @jonrsharpe platform.processor is to select particular uC?

Comment: @NikAsawadekar why don't you try it and see?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah I tried it and found that it gives the processor status of PC you are using. 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel'

Answer (score -1):

You can check the OS, just import `platform` from the `sys` module:

```
from sys import platform
if _platform == "linux" or _platform == "linux2":
    # linux
elif _platform == "darwin":
    # OS X
elif _platform == "win32":
    # Windows...
```

This should do the job for you and for the uC chip, I am not clear, wait for someone else to answer :)

Comment: The OP already knows how to get the OS, it's the processor they're interested in

Comment: oh, I misunderstood him

Comment: @NaumanAhmad Yeah, code for separate OS is written and it works. I want to know how can we do the same for some specific uC or any particular testing tool that we want to consider.